# Reading from tape

Tags: io, blocking, centos5

I want to read data from a tape and store that data on disk as a virtual tape. How to I maintain the original block structure of the tape? Some of the data I have requires the block structure stays the same. How to I establish what the block structure is on the source tape? I was thinking of writing the blocks to file with a header and footer structure and then using that to write back to tape/virtual tape maintaining the block structure. I can't work out how to establish the block structure of the data of the incoming data. I am doing this on Linux(Centos) in C. Language is not critical, will accept help in any language.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, your analysis is correct. Tape will not maintain any structure of files which it has. You should use "file marks" to find out the location of a file in a tape.

Actually process of writing a set of files to a tape goes something like this : Write 1st file, Write 1st filemark, Write 2nd file, Write 2nd filemark & so on. While restoring, for example, you need 2nd file to be restore, just jump to the 1st filemark on the tape & start reading it using ReadFile, till you reach the next file mark.

Here are some APIs you can use to do these operations said above :

- Writing a file to tape : BackupRead & WriteFile
- Write a file mark : [WriteTapeMark](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362668(v=vs.85).aspx)
- Restoring a file from tape : ReadFile & BackupWrite
- Jumping to a filemark : [SetTapePosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362536(v=vs.85).aspx)

In case any doubts arise, please get back to me.